# Example of homogenization of ideal not generated by homogenization of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ideals

I'm looking for an example of an ideal $I=\langle f_1,f_2\rangle\subseteq k[x_1,x_2]$ such that $I^h=\langle g^h:g\in I\rangle$ is not generated by $\{f_1^h,f_2^h\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example in $k[x,y]$.**

Let $I=(xy,xy+x)$. We have $x\in I$ but $x\not\in (xy,xy+zx)$.

**More interesting example in $k[x,y,z]$.**

Consider the ideal
$$I = (x^2-y,x^3-z).$$
We have $$(x^3-z)-x(x^2-y)=xy-z\in I$$ and hence
$xy-zu\in I^h$ (homogenized with respect to a variable $u$).

However, $xy-zu\not\in (x^2-yu,x^3-zu^2)$. This is easy to see, since any polynomial of degree two in the latter ideal must be a multiple of $x^2 - yu$.